# Which Connecter Is The Correct One

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata

I have a `Compaq 5008MT` desktop, with the standard hard drive & DVD Drive installed.  I purchased a 1 TB Sata drive, and opened it up only to realize, I have a free SATA connecter on the motherboard, but no free power connector (if I am explaining that properly, the slim connector has an open space on the motherboard and back of hard drive, but the wider connector is what I am missing).  There are multiple Female IDE connectors that are free, and I was thinking I could get an IDE to SATA connector, but want to be 100% certain I get the right one.  Will this get my drive up and running?  Reason I want to verify is I have one Sata To IDE Molex, but the piece is about .5 inches to wide to fit this drive, so it's not a 1 size fits all as I originally assumed.

[IDE To SATA Molex](http://www.directron.com/idesatapower.html?gsear=1)

**EDIT**

And the drive I want to add is WD5000AAKX

Comment: I'd first calculate whether your PSU can manage another device. You want to be careful not to plug something in that means it more W then what it can manage. For example, if you have a 650W PSU, if all the components required 600-650 to manage, adding on another HDD is going to mess with it. \

Comment: @AaronLayfield - if the PSU can handle it would that be the proper piece?  My next step is to upgrade PSU then add RAM

Comment: No problems should arise in using the converter. The converter will do the hard work for you. I'd just be pretty surprised if you've got no power cables left that your PSU could manage it (Generally manufactures install enough to handle what the PSU can manage).

Comment: @AaronLayfield - I was shocked as well.  There are only 2 SATA connectors and about 4 IDE connectors but not the long skinny "tape" needed for power to the IDE device, so why have the IDE connectors?

Comment: HP Microtower. May well have just been produced for masses and not expected to be upgraded. Bare minimum. Apparently it only has a 300W PSU (http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04118381.pdf) I'd be very surprised if you could add to this. *Edit, ignore my concerns, HD only takes like 10W to power. So, don't worry.

Comment: Due to PSU requirements?  If I upgraded the PSU 1st would I be able to?

Comment: Actually, I've check average power consumption and HDD tend to only need a small amount of power (http://www.buildcomputers.net/power-consumption-of-pc-components.html). I wouldn't take this as gospel, but it can't be far off.

Comment: @AaronLayfield - so the connector I l inked to would suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a SATA data cable and an adapter for a 4 pin molex (LP4) to a SATA (15 pin) standard internal power connector . Like a StarTech SATAPOWADAP. Or use a 15 + 7 adapter that has an LP4 male power connector and a 7 pin SATA Data connector (SATA10POW).
If your drive is an eSATA drive it will require different adapters.

Comment: I don't believe it's an esata, I guess I could have added the drive specs in my initial post, I will update.  It is a WD5000AAKX

Comment: That drive is 6.8 watts during read/write operations. Should be able to handle it. Is your computer model a 500B MT or 5008MT?

Comment: It is a 5008MT.